# Some guidance request on 'custom defined' resultsets

Tags: ravendb

I would like some guidance/thoughts on the route to create a functionality that allows me to let user customize their datasets. I have added an image showing this functionality but it has been called queues here.

A view is a segmentation of a resultset where the conditions are defined by either the system (default views) or the user.

I can create predefined indexes/projections for the default views that are under my control but I am stuck on the approach when a user should be able to create custom views.

- I can create one big index with all properties, and only query those fields on the index that are in the conditions defined by the user. But in that scenario the index is just one big blob of information. It is probably the easiest way but it feels ugly.
- I can dynamically create a new index, based on the entered conditions. Never explored the options of runtime defined indexes before though.
- I can dynamically create a query with conditions, however I will have to deal with stale results because I let RavenDB define the index; I would like to avoid index creation by RavenDB if possible.

Some guidance would be highly appreciated; how and with what parts of RavenDB can I efficiently accomplish this? I am not in search of a complete solution, since this is a personal project experimenting with RavenDB.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question might be too broad/generic but here's my two cents.

Yes, I agree that one massive index would not be optimal. In many cases you can get creative by breaking down an index into smaller indexes.

I don't suggest that you create run-time indexes based on how an user is using the application. That's what dynamic indexes are for. RavenDB will create a an index and manage its importance. So, you have dynamic indexes that don't get used anymore, RavenDB will abandon them. If you're worried about staleness, you can wait for non-stale results.

I'm not clear on your use-case, but maybe you could design your app it in such a way that you save all the views (custom or default) into Raven documents. For example, given the picture you attached, "unassigned issues" and "due this week" would be two separate documents. This could allow you to keep a small number of static indexes.